# Struct size stays the same even after adding a new member to it

Tags: c++, string, struct

when is simply execute

```
cout << sizeof(string);
```

i got 8 as answer.

now i am having a structure

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    string str;
} myType;
```

and i am executing

```
cout << sizeof(myType);
```

i got 16 as the answer.

now i made a change in my structure

```
typedef struct {
    int a, b;
    string str;
} myType;
```

and i am executing

```
cout << sizeof(myType);
```

i got 16 as the answer!!!. How? What is happening?

Comment: The compiler configuration at ideone.com (http://ideone.com/6LYvXN) yields 12 as the size of the struct.

Comment: Please do NOT do

    typedef struct {
    ...
    } typename;

That is C. While it is allowed in C++ for backward compatibility, it is not idiomatic. It's downright annoying. Use

    struct typename 
    {
    ...
    };

Comment: Thanks @Rob K I will keep this in mind and I wont repeat this again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps [padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) is happening. E.g. `sizeof(int)` can be 4 bytes and compiler can add 4 bytes after `a` for the sake of data alignment. The layout could be like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int a;      // 4 bytes
                // 4 bytes for padding
    string str; // 8 bytes
} myType;

typedef struct {
    int a;      // 4 bytes
    int b;      // 4 bytes
    string str; // 8 bytes
} myType;
```

Comment: sizeof(int) is 4 bytes only

Comment: @Venkatesh This is what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like 8 byte alignment.

So if you have any data type that has less than 8 bytes, it will still use 8 bytes.

I assume the pointer is 8 byte, whereas the ints are only 4 bytes each.

You can force 1 byte alignment using code like outlined here [Struct one-byte alignment conflicted with alignment requirement of the architecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906761/struct-one-byte-alignment-conflicted-with-alignment-requirement-of-the-architect) . You should then get different size for first case.

Comment: "So if you have any data type that has less than 8 bytes, it will still use 8 bytes" that's not quite true. `std::string` is aligned to 8 bytes in this case, so not any data will use 8 bytes, it depends what comes after that data.

Comment: Yes, in this case. I assume that std::string is 8 bytes here since it is a (64 bit) pointer and also 8 byte aligned?!

Answer (score 0):

It's called structure packing to achieve optimal memory alignment.

See [The Lost Art of C Structure Packing](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/) to understand the how and why. It's done the same way in both C and C++.

Answer (score -2):

In C/C++ structs are "packed" in byte chunks. You can specify which size your structs should be packed.
Here a reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx

Comment: In C data in structs aligned the same way as in C++

Comment: yes, that's perfectly right, indeed C++ is C based... why the -1?

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The examples in the link does explain the why of sizeof results.

Comment: @cabbi: We are not here to leave links, but to answer questions.